# htop - why does cpu% much higher than cpu core %?

Tags: rhel, mysql, cpu-usage, htop

So I have htop running on my RHEL 7.5 64-bit and noticed something I've not seen before.

I have 4-core and it shows that the % used fluctuates but never over 95% for each one.

However, when I look at the CPU% column, it varies greatly from 92% to even 307% over time.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

It's mostly mysql.. is that normal?

Thanks

Comment: Do you *expect* mysql to be running on the system? And do you expect it to be doing some work?

Comment: cpu% is the used across all cores, so maxing 4 CPUs would be 400%.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: For illustrative purposes.. thank you everyone.. that is what I thought as well.. spread over 4 cpu's and added

Answer (score 1):

Your `mysqld` process is utilizing multiple cores. As @jordanm pointed out in the comments 4 CPUs (cores) results with 400% CPU to use.

`72.1% + 71.9% + 18.4% + 3.2% = 165.6%`. Which encompasses the `~163%` being utilized by `mysqld`. Obviously, other processes are using the CPU too causing the math above to be more than 163%.